# Does Django support custom language codes?

Tags: python, django, internationalization

I need longer language codes for my project than two or five character long ones.

By default Django support languages which have language code like "en" for English and "en-GB" for English (British).

Is there way to use longer language codes (8 characters). This is needed for my project which uses Glottolog cataloque https://glottolog.org/glottolog/language for languages.

I have tried add LANGUAGES = [("aari1239", "Aari"),] in project settings. With this language I can create po-files. But when I try to switch language with POST-request to /i18n/setlang/ default language English is set to language.